# Logging Errors between solutions

Tags: c#, vb.net, error-handling, logfile

I try to accomplish the following task:I have `Solution1` where I write my Business Logic and `Solution 2` where I connect to e.g. PowerPoint. I have everyday tasks in this solution so I use it for many Projects. `Class1` loops over many files in a folder and extracts Text from Powerpoint Sheets by Texboxnames. The connection and extraction is done by `Solution 2` where I want to implement an `ErrorHandler` that catches the Errors as strings. These strings I want to save in a `Logfile` in `Solution1`.

**My Problem** is that as soon as there is an error in `Solution2` I need a "`Exit For`" in Solution1 but I cannot write the "`Exit For`" in my `Solution2`.

[image: Log File Problem]

Comment: if solution2 throws an exception it will be caught by solution1, which can then log it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, there are two solutions. The first but possibly not the correct one from an architectural point of view is to have an output parameter in your readfromPoserPointTextbox containing the error text.

The more correct approach would be to have a shared logging class (There are free third party logging implementations that allow you to do this without reinventing the wheel.) available to both solutions and allow each solution to handle its own logging.